# Subtracting strings (that are numbers) in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, math

I made a shell script that finds the size of a directory, returning it in human readable format (e.g., 802M or 702K). I want to calculate the difference between the sizes.

Here's my shell script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_remote_dir_size=789M
new_remote_dir_size=802M
new_size=`echo ${new_remote_dir_size} | grep -o [0-9]*`
current_size=`echo ${current_remote_dir_size} | grep -o [0-9]*`

echo "${new_size}-${current_size}"
```

But the output of the script is just

```
-
```

How can I make the subtraction work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do basic integer math in bash by wrapping the expression in `$((` and `))`.

```
$ echo $(( 5 + 8 ))
13
```

In your specific case, the following works for me:

```
$ echo "${new_size}-${current_size}"
802-789
$ echo $(( ${new_size}-${current_size} ))
13
```

Your output at the end is a bit odd. Check that the grep expression actually produces the desired output. If not, you might need to wrap the regular expression in quotation marks.

Comment: Hmm, I still get an error. I changed the last line to `echo $((${new_size} - ${current_size}))`, but then I get an operand error.

Comment: @mr_schlomo It works on my system. See my edited post. Make sure the `grep` actually works as you expect it to.

Comment: Ooops! Yep, `grep` was the problem. I just ran my script on my Linux server and it worked!

Comment: You can also do aritmethic operations using the following syntax: `echo $[ 5 + 8 ]` and with variables: `echo $[ new_size + current_size ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call out to grep to strip letters from your strings:

```
current_remote_dir_size=789M
current_size=${current_remote_dir_size%[A-Z]}
echo $current_size  # ==> 789

new_remote_dir_size=802M
new_size=${new_remote_dir_size%[A-Z]}
echo $new_size      # ==> 802
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the bash manual.

Comment: But this would silently substract 802k-789M. :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
echo $((${new_remote_dir_size/M/}-${current_remote_dir_size/M/}))
```

- $((a+b - 4)) can be used for arithmetic expressions
- ${string/M/} replaces M in string with nothing. See `man bash`, Section String substitution, for more possibilities and details.